# Extract multiword expressions from annotated text

Tags: python, dataframe

I have two columns in my dataframe, one with text and one with an annotation for each `mwe` in my text, that indicates the type of `mwe` and the range of characters where this word is included. For example,

Text column:

```
Barack Obama was president of the United States in 2008.
```

Annotation column:

```
MWE_type 0 12
```

This indicates from char 0 to 12, so the word is Barack Obama. And,

```
MWE_type 34 47
```

So, it is United States

How can I use the annotation to extract the words from the text and save them in a new column (for the example text will be something like [Barack Obama, United States] ) ?

Thank you for your time! If you need something more specific I will be glad to add some information!

Comment: how far you've tried?

Comment: I don't know how to start, so any help will be appriciated! :)

Comment: in which format the data are kept in the annotation column? are they simple plain string?

Comment: Yes, only simple string. I create the column from multiple txt files.

Comment: So, your dataframe is something like this: `{'text' : ['Barack Obama was president of the United States in 2008.'],
    'annotation' : [['MWE_type 0 12','MWE_type 34 47']]}` and each row of the `annotation` column can be a list of string, right?

Comment: Each row of the annotation column is more like a unique string.

Comment: Oh I see, so, you'll get either `MWE_type 0 12` or `MWE_type 34 47`, not both in a single row, right?

Comment: Both in a single line.

Comment: Can't you just post a small sample df? It would really help clarify the data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I didn't get you wrong, based on your definition in the comments of the main post, I've figured out a way that will do the job.

First, according to you, the data will look like this:

```
data = {'text' : ['Barack Obama was president of the United States in 2008.'],
    'annotation' : ['MWE_type 0 12 MWE_type 34 47']}
```

We will maintain a `final_list` which is basically a list of list, where is inner list will be the output for each row.

We can iterate over each row by `df.iterrows()` and extract the result for each row from `row['text']` and using `row['annotation']`.

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
```

We can extract the pair of indexes through the use of regular expression:

```
re.findall(r'\d+ \d+', row['annotation'])
```

We can iterate over this list of index pairs and append the corresponding substring to our row based result list.

```
for indexes in index_list:
        start, end = map(int, indexes.split())
        result.append(row['text'][start:end])
```

At the end of iterating a row, we can append the row based result list to the `final_list`:

```
final_list.append(result)
```

Finally, assign the `final_list` to `df['result']`:

```
df['result'] = final_list
```

The whole program is as below:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

data = {'text' : ['Barack Obama was president of the United States in 2008.'],
    'annotation' : ['MWE_type 0 12 MWE_type 34 47']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

final_list = []

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    result = []
    index_list = re.findall(r'\d+ \d+', row['annotation'])
    for indexes in index_list:
        start, end = map(int, indexes.split())
        result.append(row['text'][start:end])
    final_list.append(result)

df['result'] = final_list

print(df)
```

And you'll get:

```
                                                text  ...                         result
0  Barack Obama was president of the United State...  ...  [Barack Obama, United States]
```